# One div mirrored in several locations on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a one-page website with a layout made of horizontally sliding sections. There is a somewhat complex form at the end of each section. The form is always the same between sections, and if a bit of it is filled in one, changes should appear in all.

My question is: what is the best approach for this?

I want the website to be as lightweight as possible as it is meant to be used in very underdeveloped countries. (I haven't had to require jquery so far but it is still an option).

My best idea so far is replicating the form on page load but it will require loads of script to live update each form when the user modifies one.

**Isn't there a possibility to just mirror a div? That all the instances of the form would actually be the same div unic appearing in multiple places?**

Comment: Are you using any server sided language?  Most languages (ASP.Net, CakePHP, PHP) allow you to create controls (or templates, views, etc) that can be created once but can be copied and inserted into a page multiple times.  Just like a text box has one class but multiple instances, so could your control.

Comment: Both .clone() and a "inserting multiple times an item" are very static solutions and both non optimal for loading time. What I'm looking for is a way to have all instances identical at all times, even during interaction. Like if it was the same unic form seen in different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate the data of input as it changed?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bla!</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function duplicate(object) {
                var data = object.value;
                inputs = document.getElementsByName(object.name);
                for (var i in inputs) {
                    var input = inputs[i];
                    input.value = data;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class='body' >
        <div id='div1'>
            <h2>Form1</h2>
            <form>
                <input onchange='duplicate(this);' name='input1'>
                <input onchange='duplicate(this);' name='input2'>
                <input onchange='duplicate(this);' name='input3'>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id='div2'>
            <h2>Form2</h2>
            <form>
                <input onchange='duplicate(this);' name='input1'>
                <input onchange='duplicate(this);' name='input2'>
                <input onchange='duplicate(this);' name='input3'>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id='div3'>
            <h2>Form3</h2>
            <form>
                <input onchange='duplicate(this);' name='input1'>
                <input onchange='duplicate(this);' name='input2'>
                <input onchange='duplicate(this);' name='input3'>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks simple enough. Most of my inputs are radios though so it would be a little less straightforward with this method (I have to either iterate over the set or use queryselector).
What I don't really like about having to actually duplicate the whole form is that I use labels to refer to my radio inputs for styling, thus needing ids. If I duplicate I either have to tweak ids (seems like unnecessary js) or to live with multiple identical ids...

Comment: I realize now that this is probably the most lightweight answer there could be.